# Setting up GitLab CI on server with GitLab already installed

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a server running CentOS 6.5, and I have already installed GitLab on it. I wanted to install GitLab CI as well - will installing it overwrite my current GitLab installation or is it completely separate from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use both GitLab and GitLab CI all on the same host and it works fine - they are totally separate applications and work well together. Each application is installed into it's own home. I don't, but you could also run the GitLab CI Runner on the same box too.

Just follow the GitLab CI how-to and you'll be up and running in no time!

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/5-2-stable/doc/install/installation.md

Comment: did you have to change the URLS for the gitlab, and gitlab ci? it is not very clear in the docs , it seems to request it as a requirement, i wanted to make sure. tia

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to use:

- [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)
- a DockerFile (like [`darthmuffins/gitlab-ci-runner-centos/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/darthmuffins/gitlab-ci-runner-centos/blob/master/Dockerfile), or the project [`sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-runner`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-runner)) in order to make a separate GitLab CI instance (running on the same server but acting like its own independent server).

In your case, that might be difficult, since CentOS 6.5 is built from the source packages of RHEL 6 update 5 (also known as RHEL version 6.5, kernel 2.6.32-431), which means Docker might not be fully supported.

Comment: I have never used Docker before, and I'm kind of struggling setting up everything as is. I'd like to at least get a stable setup before I move onto doing anything else, first.

Comment: @HassanKhan I understand. The nice thing about Docker is the isolation it provides. You can try multiple setup in a Docker Container without disrupting your existing server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I do know what Docker does, it's just becoming a bit overwhelming with all I have to do right now.